# Check URL parameter by name and get number

Tags: php

I have parameter like this.

`www.domain.com/index.php?r=yes/no&param1=thisOneforAnotherUse`

in `param1` parameter, I want to convert it into `param = 1` when I catch it from `$_['GET']` method.

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are the critera of splitting param1?

Comment: the parameter name will be `param<number>` always?

Comment: @Himanshu Yes, `<number>` is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use regular expression to separate text and number.

`preg_match_all('/(.*)(\d+), $input, $output);`

And just list your output with print_r() for check result.

Comment: to separate text and number was not the main question.

Comment: yes, but you can convert it into your expected format

Comment: Yes, but this is the correct one: `preg_match('/param(.*)/',$string, $matches);`

Comment: I think I want to close the question while lazy people want to close it.

Comment: Okay, we've regexpr, so now you can get required data. I don't know what do you want.